# Open new meeting request from web application

Tags: outlook, protocols

The easiest way I can describe what I want to do is this:
I want the functionality of `mailto:`, but instead of opening a new email on the client's machine, I want it to open a new meeting request (ideally with certain fields already filled in, such as subject, attendees, etc.). At that point, the user can change the meeting request however they want (or just close it and do nothing with it).

While it would be nice if the solution was pretty universal, my main concern is that it works with the Outlook clients (Windows, Mac, iOS, Android).

I've looked into `webcals://` and `.ics`, and, from what I can tell, that's not what I really want as that is how to add meetings to calendars that have been created -- I want the current user to create the meeting.

I'm aware that OWA (Office 365) has specific links you can use to do this, but some users still have mailboxes on premises.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that works for me. I will not be marking this as the correct answer as it does not answer my original question and may not be a viable solution for others.

Teams is used by my organization and has the ability to schedule meetings. There is a deep link available to navigate the user to the screen (either via browser or desktop application) to create a meeting with fields populated for them.

Here's the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-the-scheduling-dialog). I have included the relevant information below:

> Example: `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meeting/new?subject=test subject&amp;attendees=joe@contoso.com,bob@contoso.com&amp;startTime=10-24-2018 10:30:00&amp;endTime=10-24-2018 10:30:00&amp;content=test-content`
>
> The query parameters are:
>
> - `attendees` The optional comma-separated list of user IDs representing the attendees of the meeting. The user performing the action is the meeting organizer. The User ID field currently only  supports the Azure AD UserPrincipalName (typically an email  address).
> - `startTime` The optional start time of the event. This should be in long ISO 8601 format, for example “2018-03-12T23:55:25+02:00”.
> - `endTime` The optional end time of the event, also in ISO 8601 format.
> - `subject` An optional field for the meeting subject.
> - `content` An optional field for the meeting details field.
>
> Currently, specifying the location is not supported. When generating your start and end times be sure to specify the UTC offset  (time
> zones).

Comment: It works great! But i have one more requirement. How to add optional attendees to the meeting invite through deeplink ?
And also is it possible to open outlook meeting invitation window instead of Teams?